# how to create a "my comments" view

Tags: views, comments

I just want to create a view that show each user their own set of comments only. would I add something in contextual filters?

Thanks 
Tony

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, add the contextual filter "Comment Author uid". Then, under the section "When the filter value is NOT available", select,

"provide a default value".

You can then select:

"User ID from logged in user"

or

"User ID from URL".

To use the latter, you will have to display the view as a block on a page that has the user->uid in the system path, such as the user account page (user/%uid). If you use the former, the view can be displayed anywhere, and will always show the current user's comments.